# Difference between an If statement and While loop

Tags: php

I read this Manual by PHP.com about [While loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php).

I don't understand the purpose of While loops in PHP.

It looks exactly like an `if` statement to me.

What is the difference between an if statement and a while loop?

How do while loops work, what do they do, and when should I use them?

For example, can't this:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;
}
```

be done like this?:

```
$i = 1;
if ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;
}
```

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: don't over think it. what does `if` mean in the real world? a one-time decision. same in PHP. make a decision once, move onwards. what does `while` mean in the real world? "until some condition becomes satisified, continue doing this..." same in PHP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An `if` statement checks if an expression is true or false, and then runs the following code block only if it is true. The code inside the block is **only run once**...

```
if (x > y)
{
   // this will only happen once
}
```

A `while` statement is a loop. Basically, **it continues to execute** the code in the following block for however long the expression is true.

```
while (x > y)
{
  // this will keep happening until the condition is false.
}
```

**When to use a while loop:**

While loops are best used when you don't know exactly how many times you may have to loop through a condition - if you know exactly how many times you want to test a condition (e.g. 10), then you'd use a for loop instead.

Comment: Oh I get it now.. when is the while loop is basically important? I mean I can't find any useful usages with it.

Comment: @Jony While loops are best used when you don't know exactly how many times you may have to loop through a condition - if you know exactly how many times you want to test a condition (e.g. 10), then you'd use a for loop instead.

Comment: When you want to keep doing something until a condition is met - for example, reading results from a database query.

Answer (score 7):

A while loop will run as many times as it needs to while a condition is true, i.e., *until that condition is false*.

An if statement will execute **once** if a condition is true.

A great way to understand concepts like this when you're just learning a language is to try them out:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;
}

echo "\n";

$i = 1;
if ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;
}
```

This results in:

```
12345678910
1
```

Comment: Please include relevant code samples in the answer itself, rather than linking to external content.

Answer (score 1):

if command is only run in one condition in one time  and its execute in only one statement in one time

while loop is manly use in infinite time for looping a statement while is executed in many statement in one time

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example:

Suppose you want a script that loops through an array and make one beep sound for each element of the array.

A WHILE loop would generate no beeps for an empty array.

An FOR loop will always run at least once, so an empty array would generate one beep.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. FOR loops aren't mentioned. Can you explain how a WHILE loop differs from an IF statement.