# IF loop inside a function in python

Tags: python, opencv, for-loop, while-loop, hough-transform

I have a function that I would like to perform an `if` statement inside of. I know this is not possible in Python so I have added a `while` loop before I implement the `if` statement but it seems like the `while` loop is not stopping, or perhaps it maybe another issue.

```
def hough(frame): 
    
    #calculate the median 
    medianFrame = np.median(randframes,axis=0).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
    grayMedianFrame = cv2.cvtColor(medianFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    gframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #grayscale frame
    dframe = cv2.absdiff(gframe, grayMedianFrame)  #remove background

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(dframe,(11,11),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)  #Gausian blur with standard deviation of 11
    
    while True: 
        
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,120,param1= 50, param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
        
        if circles is None: 
            radius.append(0)
            continue
        
        else: 
            circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
            
            for j in circles[0, :]: 
            
                # draw the outer circle
                cv2.circle(frame, (j[0], j[1]), j[2], (0, 0, 255), 2)
                # draw the center of the circle
                cv2.circle(frame, (j[0], j[1]), 2, (0, 255, 0), 9)
                
                radius.append(circles[0][0][2])
     
       break 

    return frame
```

The varaibles not defined inside the function have been done so but for the purpose of simplicity I have not included them.

**EDIT**: I have made some changes thanks to the comments, however the issue still exists

**EDIT 2**: The code works fine but it seems to be an issue when `cirlces` return `None`.

Comment: `if` is not a loop

Comment: do you want to get out of the while loop if the condition is true?

Comment: Of course the `while` loop does not stop.  You've given it no condition under which it will stop.  What was this supposed to accomplish, anyway?  Every call to `cv2.HoughCircles()` has exactly the same parameters, so it's going to presumably return exactly the same result each time.

Comment: @ForceBru Ah yes, it is a statement. My bad!

Comment: Wait, what? I’m sure that if statements *are* allowed inside functions.

Comment: @GitGoodCodes, it seems you want to append values to a list called `radius` inside a loop? The first issue here is that as far as I can see, the  `radius` list does not exist, unless it is global (which it really should not be). From what I can see though, with each cycle of this while loop nothing changes. `circles` is generated exactly the same every time, so it is unclear why you are using a loop at all. What do you want this code to achieve?

Comment: @quamrana I recently found this to be not true. Perhaps I am wrong

Comment: @GitGoodCodes with your changes you still have no ```break``` inside your while to jump out of it.What do you want to achive?

Comment: @FinleyGibson Yes, you are correct. The `radius` is a global variable. I believe this was the correct decision as I can use the values inside this list in the future for purposes such as plots etc. The purpose of this function is to find a circle on a frame through `cv2.HoughCircles()`. `circles` is then used to find its radius. The function will be used in a `for` loop for multiple frames.

Comment: @MaKaNu I have now added the `break`. Is this correct?

Comment: @GitGoodCodes from your last comment: Why do you want to while-loop? Using Globals is in most cases [anti-pattern](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/using_the_global_statement.html). The linked Site provides solution for your mentioned Problem

Comment: @GitGoodCodes somehow yes, but it results in running just one time through, so the ```while-loop``` is obsolete. See my [awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65074800/10985257) for a good implementation of Hough.

Comment: So what is the intended purpose of the loop? A loop is used when you want to repeat some process multiple times, I cannot see what you wish to repeat here. You are repeatedly calculating the radius of `circles`, but why are you doing this repeatedly, and what do you expect to be different each time?

Comment: @FinleyGibson The reason I have included the `while` loop is that I wanted to implement an `if` statement inside the function. The reason for this is that each frame will consist of a circle of different radius.

Comment: Did you looked inside my link? They have a Solution for the situation ```circles == None```. Further I recommend to change your title, because it doesn't match you Problem anymore.

Comment: @quamrana It works without the while loop. I guess I was wrong :)

Comment: @MaKaNu I am looking at the moment. It does have the solution for 'circles == None'.  Thank you very much! I also found out I have no need of the `while` loop.

Comment: Great that was it the hole time, what I want to tell you. Nice to hear you figured it out.

Comment: @GitGoodCodes, sounds like you have figured out that you don't need the while. Assuming you have several frames you want to process, I put together an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075666/10111013) with a modified version which does what I think you are trying to achieve (and avoids referencing `radius` from within the function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assume at the Moment that you just want a working Hough Transform function. There is a good example from OpenCV itself. Providing solutions for `Java`, `C++` and `python`:

[Hough Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment so writing it here,
Your requirement is not so much clear, first of all `if` is not a loop, secondly there is nothing we can understand when to break the While loop, i am simplifying your issue, here is sample Code.

```
if circles is None: 
     radius.append(0)
     continue
else:
     break
```

The `continue` in this situation is also not necessary since after the `if` no more code to run inside the `while`

Answer (score 0):

Before replying, let me point that `if` command refers to a statement, and not a loop (more infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606466/difference-between-an-if-statement-and-while-loop))

According to [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue):

> The continue statement is used to skip the rest of the code inside a
> loop for the current iteration only.

In your specific case, when the condition of the if statement is True, you append the value 0 to the radius list and then you continue with the next iteration of the while loop. Since the loop is `while True:` it continues infinitely.
If what you wanted to achieve was to exit from the loop when the condition on the if statement is achieved, then one way may be to use the `break` operator instead the `continue` one.

Answer (score 0):

```
def hough(frame): 
    
    #calculate the median 
    medianFrame = np.median(randframes,axis=0).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
    grayMedianFrame = cv2.cvtColor(medianFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    gframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #grayscale frame
    dframe = cv2.absdiff(gframe, grayMedianFrame)  #remove background

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(dframe,(11,11),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)  #Gausian blur with standard deviation of 11

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,120,param1= 50, param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
        
    if circles is None: 
        return [0]
    else: 
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        output = []  
        for j in circles[0, :]: 
            
            # draw the outer circle
            cv2.circle(frame, (j[0], j[1]), j[2], (0, 0, 255), 2)
            # draw the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(frame, (j[0], j[1]), 2, (0, 255, 0), 9)
                
           output.append(circles[0][0][2])
    return output


## main program
radius = []
for frame in frames:
    radius.append(hough(frame))
```

Comment: Thank you Finley. This certainly seems like a better way of doing it!